# create a (Prawn) PDF inside custom DelayedJob and upload it to S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, paperclip, delayed-job, prawn, rails-activejob

Using: Rails 4.2, Prawn, Paperclip, DelayedJobs via ActiveJobs, Heroku.

I have a PDF that is very large and needs to be handled in the background.  Inside a custom Job I want to create it, upload it to S3, and then email the user with a url when its ready.  I facilitate this via a PdfUpload model.

Is there anything wrong with my approach/code?  Im using File.open() as outlined in examples I found, but this seems to be the root of my error ( TypeError: no implicit conversion of FlightsWithGradesReport into String ).

```
  class PdfUpload < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :report,
      path: "schools/:school/pdf_reports/:id_:style.:extension"
  end
```

/pages_controller.rb

```
  def flights_with_grades_report
    flash[:success] = "The report you requested is being generated.  An email will be sent to '#{ current_user.email }' when it is ready."
    GenerateFlightsWithGradesReportJob.perform_later(current_user.id, @rating.id)
    redirect_to :back
    authorize @rating, :reports?
  end
```

/ the job

```
class GenerateFlightsWithGradesReportJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :generate_pdf

  def perform(recipient_user_id, rating_id)
    rating = Rating.find(rating_id)
    pdf = FlightsWithGradesReport.new( rating.id )
    pdf_upload = PdfUpload.new
    pdf_upload.report = File.open( pdf )
    pdf_upload.report_processing = true
    pdf_upload.report_file_name = "report.pdf"
    pdf_upload.report_content_type = "application/pdf"
    pdf_upload.save!
    PdfMailer.pdf_ready(recipient_user_id, pdf_upload.id)
  end
end
```

This results in an error:

```
 TypeError: no implicit conversion of FlightsWithGradesReport into String
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing this:

```
pdf_upload.report = File.open( pdf )
```

to this:

```
pdf_upload.report = StringIO.new(pdf.render)
```

fixed my problem.